# Why use long[] instead of Date[]?

Tags: java, coding-style, date-formatting

[I read this coding rule](http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/garbagecollection.html#rule6) that states you should prefer the use of `long[]` over `Date[]`, but there is no reference provided as to *why*.

Why should I do this?  What is the advantage of using a `long` over `Date`?  What effect will this have on garbage collection?  Or is this just a bunch of nonsense?

Comment: Without any context such a rule doesn't make much sense.

Comment: I think the Rational Application Developer(@drgomesp) has j used other sources for his coding rules. I found the rule here: http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/garbagecollection.html#rule6 but no explanation why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone else stumbles upon this question:

> I'm not trying to be a smartass :) But the fact that you have only one object (which in fact is an array of 10000 longs) or if you have 10001 objects (one being the array, and 10000 Dates) is a huge difference for the garbage collector

from [Lukas Eder](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521799/lukas-eder)

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you're trying to achieve. For example, `long[]` has a smaller memory requirement than `Date[]` (because `Date` is an Object and `long` is a primative), but is that really important for your purpose?

Comment: Correct - I was referring more to the content of the array rather than the array object itself, but thanks for being more technically correct  :-)

Comment: I'm not trying to be a smartass :) But the fact that you have only one object (which in fact is an array of 10000 `longs`) or if you have 10001 objects (one being the array, and 10000 `Dates`) is a huge difference for the garbage collector

Comment: I think the answer from Lukas Eder is correct: http://www.appperfect.com/support/java-coding-rules/garbagecollection.html#rule6

Answer (score -3):

I believe it is because you can get a lot of problems with databases using the Date.

Comment: some databases do not recognize the Date type.. I've had my problems with this, solved by saving them as UNIX timestamps (long's)